# React Native issue with state and initialRegion in MapView component

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a MapView that I'm trying to have focus on a user's current location. Right now I'm logging the position, and logging the currentRegion state. My issue is the component is showing the empty array in the log, and after it cycles through render it sets the state as the position coordinates, so that the MapView shows me somewhere in the middle of the ocean. Why isn't initialRegion grabbing the changed state and rendering?

```
 const screen = Dimensions.get('window');
    const ASPECT_RATIO = screen.width / screen.height;

    var LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.3022;
    var LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

    class MapScreen extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          currentRegion: []
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            console.log(position)
            this.setState({ currentRegion: {
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
              longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
            }})
          },
          (error) => alert(error.message),
          {timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
        )
      }

      render () {
        console.log(this.state.currentRegion)
        return(

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
              showsUserLocation = {true}
              style={styles.map}
              initialRegion={this.state.currentRegion}
            />
          </View>
        )
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 4):

After lots of searches I finally got the solution.
This works for me everytime.

just replace "initialRegion" with "region".

Answer (score 0):

The initialRegion prop does not update the region when its prop is changed after it has been mounted. By definition it is merely the initial starting point.
This is mentioned in the docs under MapView props:
 https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Because MapView is mounting before your state is updated, it uses the empty array. Try using ComponentWillMount() instead of ComponentDidMount() so that your state change happens sooner.  If that doesn't work you could also try setting the current position in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

initialRegion state should be an object. You have kept it as an array in your state.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentRegion: {
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }
    }
}
```